# az login command fails - Azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Installed Azure CLI on windows, ran az login command and running into following error

[image]

Version I am running is : 2.0.37

Comment: It seems caused by local environment, try to open a new shell to do it again.

Answer (score 5):

[Azure cli 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-azure-cli#versions-of-the-azure-cli) is written in python, it will [verify ssl certificate](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/) when setting request. Make sure you don't have any proxy setting. I met same error when fiddler is running.

To work with proxy, we have to set `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` env variable to certificate path.  See related [issue comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5099#issuecomment-378774521).

Make a complete example of fiddler.

1. Exported fiddler's certificate to desktop.
   Tools -> Options, HTTPS tab, Actions -> Export Root Certificate to Desktop.
2. Use [OpenSSL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl/) to convert to `.pem` file as Python doesn't accept `.cer` file.

   `openssl x509 -inform der -in FiddlerRoot.cer -out FiddlerRoot.pem`.
3. Configure env variable in PS: `$env:REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE= '{folderpath}\FiddlerRoot.pem'`

Then everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a command

```
az login
```

then it will try to take you though the browser and you have to provider your username and password there only.

If you want to login in the hell only then use

```
az login -u your_username -p your_password
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this with Azure CLI v2.3.2, what worked for me was copying the link it opened into a new incognito Chrome window and logging in as normal