# az login error: Please ensure you have network connection. Error detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443)

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Trying to install the Azure Devops CLI Extension

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops

```
az extension add --name azure-devops
```

is the command I run

**I get the following error message**

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeNWC.png)
**I have tried**

```
git config http.sslVerify "false"
```

**I've tried to do multiple azure cli and powershell commands**

**I've set my context with**

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

I don't understand what the issue is here.

**I've tried running the commands with and without the VPN ( I use Pulse VPN for reference)**

**I've tried setting powershell's execution policy to Undefined**

```
**Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Undefined -Scope CurrentUser**
```

**If someone could please let me know their thoughts on the specific error:**

*Please ensure you have network connection. Error detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='objects.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /github-production-release-asset-2e65be/107708057/665228bd-d0c3-4865-b029-624cbc247ca1?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20220701%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220701T163308Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=dd9381d3d71deeb228b151ec41140e8238f425ca9bf2882889c6bc9592c782e6&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=107708057&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dazure_devops-0.25.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))*

I've seen the post here [Azure CLI Error](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/15410) and it was of no help

Comment: How is this related to terraform?

Answer (score 0):

***We have tried the same at our local to install the `azure devops` extension and it works successfully by following the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops) as given in question***.

Here are the workaround we followed;

```
az login
Select-AzSubscription -Subscription subscriptionID
```

*And it has been logged in successfully:-*
[image]

*After then installing `az extension add --name azure-devops` and it works.*

[image]

*Below are `az --version` we used ;*

[image]

**NOTE:-** For the error make sure that you are using the latest version of az cli and  ***enabled the port in your local*** (*Windows security> Advance settings> Inbound Rule> add new rule then add your required port (443) and enable the same*).

*For configuration details here* : [***How to  open port in windows firwall***](https://www.howtogeek.com/394735/how-do-i-open-a-port-on-windows-firewall/)   .

*For more information please refer the below links*:-

- *Similar* [***SO THREAD|Why Azure CLI login fails? "Connection actively refused"***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582211/why-azure-cli-login-fails-connection-actively-refused) & [***az login command fails - Azure cli***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864309/az-login-command-fails-azure-cli) .
- **BLOG**| [***MICROSOFT TECHNET***](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/54013.mysterious-authentication-failure-of-az-login.aspx) .